# How to append text to the end of a line in Gvim or vi

Tags: unix, vim, text, vi

I am using gvim on windows and have a file with several lines that look like this

```
Select '305','TableA
Select '313','TableB
Select '313','TableC
```

I would like to append the following line at the end of each line.

```
', count(*) from [Tablename] where msgid in (select msgid from mainTable where row_dtm<'17NOV11')
```

The result should look something like this (Note that the [TableName] is replaced by the actual table name.

```
Select '305','TableA', count(*) from TableA where msgid in (select msgid from mainTable where row_dtm<'17NOV11')
Select '313','TableB', count(*) from TableB where msgid in (select msgid from mainTable where row_dtm<'17NOV11')
Select '313','TableC', count(*) from TableC where msgid in (select msgid from mainTable where row_dtm<'17NOV11')
```

I can add append the text at the end by just doing

```
%s/$/', count(*) from [Tablename] where msgid in (select msgid from mainTable where row_dtm<'17NOV11')/g
```

But i am stuck as to how i can read the table name and put that in place of [Tablename].

Basically i am just trying to generate several queries. Any ideas?
I know that the table name will always be the text from the end of the line to the first ' character but how do i read it and add it to the modified string?

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to do a tiny bit of back referencing.
Change the search term to:
`\(\a\+\)$` this will match the table name. Surrounding the search term with `\(` and `\)` allow it to be referenced in the replace
Add \1 to your replacement string wherever you want the tablename to appear.
The result should look like this
`%s/\(\a\+\)$/\1', count(*) from [\1] where msgid in (select msgid from mainTable where row_dtm<'17NOV11')/g`

Comment: What does \a\+ between the "\\( and \\)" do? Thanks

Comment: `\a` matches alphabet characters (a-zA-Z) and \+ matches one or more of the previous charector (\a) see [:help patttern](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pattern.html#pattern)
If your table names have numbers or symbols in them you will have to adjust that search term to compensate.

Answer (score 4):

If you select a block (using <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> (thought that may give you trouble if you're in Windows), you can append text to all lines in the block using <kbd>A</kbd>.

For instance, assume that I selected the code that is in ***bold italics*** below:

```
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, 
    sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna
    aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation 
    ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. 
    Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit 
    esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint
    occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia
    deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
```

And now I type <kbd>A</kbd> and the text `bla` followed by <kbd>ESC</kbd>.

The result is:

```
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, coblansectetur adipisicing elit, 
    sed do eiusmod tempor incididublant ut labore et dolore magna
    aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniablam, quis nostrud exercitation 
    ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquiblap ex ea commodo consequat. 
    Duis aute irure dolor in repreblahenderit in voluptate velit 
    esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nblaulla pariatur. Excepteur sint
    occaecat cupidatat non proidenblat, sunt in culpa qui officia
    deserunt mollit anim id est lablaborum.
```

Similarly, if you type <kbd>I</kbd> instead of <kbd>A</kbd>, the text will be prepended.

Answer (score 2):

You can always record a macro modifying a line and moving to the next, and then replay that macro:

```
qq$bywA', count(count(*) from <ESC>pAwhere msgid in (select msgid from mainTable where row_dtm<'17NOV11')<ESC>jq2@q
```

- `qq` → start recording a macro in register `q`.
- `$` → go to end of line.
- `b` → go back to the beginning of the previous word.
- `yw` → yank word.
- `Afoo<ESC>` → append "foo" at end of line, end insert mode with `<ESC>` key.
- `p` → paste yanked word.
- `Afoo<ESC>` → append "foo" at end of line, end insert mode with `<ESC>` key.
- `j` → go to the next line.
- `q` → end macro recording.
- `2@q` → replay macro in register `q` 2 times.